How to resolve TLS handshake failure in mitmproxy after installing certificate on Linux?
I am trying to intercept HTTPS traffic using mitmweb on my Linux machine with the following command:
mitmweb --listen-port 8082

The output shows that the proxy is running, but I encounter TLS handshake errors:
[00:40:54.910] HTTP(S) proxy listening at *:8082.
[00:40:54.912] Web server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Opening in existing browser session.
[00:40:55.930][[::1]:56158] client connect
[00:40:55.956][[::1]:56158] server connect content-autofill.googleapis.com:443 (142.250.194.74:443)
[00:40:56.086][[::1]:56158] Client TLS handshake failed. The client does not trust the proxy's certificate for content-autofill.googleapis.com (OpenSSL Error([('SSL routines', '', 'ssl/tls alert certificate unknown')]))
[00:40:57.170][[::1]:56170] Client TLS handshake failed. The client does not trust the proxy's certificate for content-autofill.googleapis.com (OpenSSL Error([('SSL routines', '', 'ssl/tls alert certificate unknown')]))

To resolve this, I installed the mitmproxy certificate following these steps:

Moved the certificate to the trusted store:
sudo mv mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mitmproxy.crt


Updated the certificate list:
sudo update-ca-certificates



However, even after performing these steps, I'm still unable to intercept HTTPS traffic, and the TLS handshake errors persist.
My goal is to intercept HTTP/HTTPS traffic from two backend services, but I am not sure how to proceed. Here's an image of the current response in mitmweb:

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

In short: you need to import the CA directly into Chrome in order for to be used by Chrome. update-ca-certificates is not sufficient
